# Why do Smart Groups now give database errors?

Tags: smartgroups, issues

I just updated from 4.6.3 to 4.6.5, on Joomla.  I have a number of Smart Groups which worked fine before, but now inconsistently fail to load contacts or settings, giving a database error instead.  The error seems related to building the cache, so I assume the inconsistency comes from whether or not it's refreshing the cache entry.

The database query that causes problems is:

```
SELECT id, cache_date, saved_search_id, children
FROM   civicrm_group
WHERE  id 0
  AND  ( saved_search_id != 0
   OR    saved_search_id IS NOT NULL
   OR    children IS NOT NULL )
```

Clearly "WHERE id 0" is invalid syntax.  The problem seems to be with changes to the CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php code.  The function addGroupContactCache used to create a clause within the function, something like "WHERE ID IN (4, 7, 10)".  Now it calls self::buildClause.

From some debugging I did, buildClause is usually called with "IN" as the $op value, in which case it generates a valid clause.  But sometimes the $op value is "=", and it returns that "id 0" clause which breaks things.

The code changes between 4.6.3 and 4.6.5 are complicated enough that I'm not sure how to quick-fix it.  Any suggestions to get our smart groups working again are very welcome!

Comment: I too am seeing odd things with smart groups in 4.6.5.  I have a number of smart groups that are based upon membership.  It has lost this info so it pulls everyone.  Also see error if I clear caches and then go to manage groups gets syntax error the sql has AND where should have WHERE: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civicrm_temp_group_contact_cache768 (SELECT 65 as group_id, contact_a.id as contact_id FROM CustomSearch_SYBNT_temp as contact_a AND contact_a.id NOT IN ( SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed' AND civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 65 ) )

Answer (score 4):

To standardize Get.api and Search form underlying where clause(s), buildClause() fn expects value(s) to be in array(operator => array(values)) format [I call it "Operator as Key" - OK format :p ]. Earlier in prior version most of the Get.api aren't working because the buildClause() was designed according to Search formValues format [array(values)], so there is conflict in how the values got retrieved and eventually result into Fatal Error/Empty Value for get.Apis. Whereas in some worst-case scenario the get.Api was only working proper with '=' operator as the buildClause didn't got the flexibility to work with any other operator other then '='. But recent changes ( 4.6 onward ) in buildClause expects values atleast for n-nary operators IN/NOT IN in the desired OK format. On the otherhand recent changes has ALSO ensured that the Search Form formvalues processed first into OK format before passing it to build-Clause.

Now back to the bug mentioned here, here's my fix https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6320. In addition buildClause will also support previous format but will through a e-notice to notify the wrong value format.

Comment: I tried the fix.  It's still building the where clause without the WHERE.  See my comment above.  I'm guessing this is a different case.   Should I file a different question/issue?

Comment: I was missing the steps to replicate the bug from UI, as you mentioned earlier, so the fix was an improvement. But if the bug still persist please file a issue with steps to replicate and if possible attach the screenshots of 46 demo site http://d46.demo.civicrm.org !!

Comment: I'll file a separate issue.  In the meantime, I get the error if I clear the civi cache and then go to the manage groups page.  It goes off and creates the cache for that page.  It churns for a while and then errors with syntax error.  I'm guessing I won't be able to reproduce in a demo database.  Some of the smart groups are based upon include exclude query which in the past has caused issues.

Comment: Thanks Monish, that seems to make the smart groups work again.  (Though I haven't done full testing.)  Unfortunately, when I try to view a contact record, it breaks with the error "Expected one Contact but found 0"

Comment: Could you provide links to the JIRA issue(s) please? Thanks.

Comment: Fixed under https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16483 and https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16922