# Patch or workaround for search with checkbox or multiselect field

Tags: search, civigrant

I believe we have a bug when search criteria includes a checkbox or multi-select fields (it may include other fields).  I created a ticket: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16947

1. Create a multiselect custom field (or checkbox text)
2. Search in advanced search and fails to pickup record
3. Search in "find grant" and fails pickup record
   That's all I've tested but it fail be elsewhere too.
   Works in API and search builder.

I reproduced on the wordpress demo site (Contact-"Omar Barkley" custom field-"test contact") I Couldn't find a specific issue on Jira.

If it were only for contacts, I could use the search builder (which works) but This is for a grant.  Need a select/checkbox for completing parts of a grant (status won't work.)

Has anyone else encountered this and/or resolved it?

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed that under https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16927 and here's the PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6342 (not merger yet). Can you please verify the patch if it works for ya ?

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try

Comment: patch applied against 4.6.5 and it didn't seem to work.  I'd have to clone and build a dev stack to test against master unless you can show me how to generate a patch against 4.6.5 for PR and affected files only.

Comment: The PR is now merged, so you could just grab the latest code from github.

Comment: A little help.  using a beta/preproduction stack (not under git). usually i can just grab a .patch from GH and apply.  This fails again as it is probably applied against master.  Should i git clone -b 4.6.5  ? If so, do i need to do for drupal too? otherwise, how do i generate a patch against 4.6.5?

Comment: Please check my comment on https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16938?focusedCommentId=77173&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-77173 of how to make/apply patch from PR. Ask me if if there is any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I had two recent similar issues.  One here ([Advanced Search error after upgrade to 4.6.5](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4124/advanced-search-error-after-upgrade-to-4-6-5)) was resolved with a rc codebase that Eileen M kindly provided.  The other ([Different search results in Adv Search vs Search Builder](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4150/different-search-results-in-adv-search-vs-search-builder/4204#4204)), which is perhaps closer to yours, I temporarily resolved by going back down to 4.6.4.  It sounds like a few search issues will be resolved when 4.6.6 comes out in a week or two.

You could try the new codebase that Eileen provided to see if that helps.  If not, 4.6.6 is perhaps your best bet.